# Adding previous and current index in Numpy Arrays Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, iterator

How could I code a function that adds to the previous index of the array without using a for loop. So for the second value in the Expected Output it will be previous index (`2`) plus current index(`5`) resulting in `7`. How would I be able to do such a thing?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2,5,44,-12,3,-5])
```

Expected output:

```
[2,7,51,39,42,37]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
np.cumsum(A)
```

Prints:

```
array([ 2,  7, 51, 39, 42, 37], dtype=int32)
```